# Background-image in body?

Tags: html, css

I am tasked with adding a background image for a home page.  However, I do not have access to the CSS file associated with the HTML document I am working on (3rd party company created / has that file).  The document I am working with consists of the HTML code's body.

Is it possible to add a background-image within the body of an HTML document?  (All the examples I have seen add it in the head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<body style="background-image: url(#);">
```

This should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 1):

There many ways to do this, but I wouldn't suggest this because it's not the professional way! Any way this is an example:

```html
<body style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg)">


<p>Content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <body background="image.png">
```

By adding image path in body you can add image without having access to css

Comment: In addition to this, you can also use `<body style="background-image: url();">` or `<body style="background: url();">`

Comment: The background attribute is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you could tackle this.

### Inline Styles on the `body` element

`<body style="background-image: url(image.jpg);">`

### Style Block

It's not the nicest technique but you could add this to your HTML

`<style>body {background: url(image.jpg);}</style>`